# Deleting Snapshots from LinkedClone Corrupts other LinkedClones

Tags: virtual-machine, clone, esxi, snapshot

I am currently having a problem in which I have 3 LinkedClones created from the same parent snapshot.

The tasks I do consists of creating a lot of snapshots per virtual machine, therefore having the need of deleting snapshots after a period of time.

Because I only need the most recent snapshots, I always delete the oldest one (the one at the top of the tree).

This action ends up changing the ID in the VMDK file of the Parent VM, causing the other 2 VMs to become unusable.

An example.

Parent creates snapshot 0, which will be used to bring clones A, B,and C.

Using these 3 clones, I keep taking snapshots over a period of time until the snapshot tree is full.

Let's take A, with snapshots: 1. 2. 3. 4. 5. 6. 7. 8.

I delete 1 to make more room. This changes the Parent's ID.

What can I do to solve this problem?

On a side note, vSphere Client tells me that it needs consolidation for VMs B and C.

Answer (score 0):

While deleting the child snapshot it should affect the parent disk's ID.

And also you are having the same disk as parent for your another two machines like say B and C as per your example. So deleting the child from Machine A is affecting the common parent disk's ID.

So it should ask for consolidation.

If you don't want the changes in your snapshot 1 from Machine A means just try to do Revert Snapshot process(Go To option in Vsphere client) then try to delete the snapshot.

If you want to retain the changes made in your Machine A means. You should have to consolidate the other two machines to run without any problem.

Another Solution:

Otherwise we can try editing the "parentCID" value in the disks descriptor which is associated with your Machine B and Machine C

But we should be cautious before changing anything in the Managed Disks.Vsphere will handle Hosted disk and Managed disk in a different manner.